# JS for screen width

Tags: javascript, meta

How do you load a file based on the browser screen size?  This is the code I'm using:

```
<script>
if(iPhone) { <- screen size instead of device
  document.write("<meta name="viewport" content=\"width=480\""+"/>");
} else {
  document.write("<meta name="viewport" content=\"width=1024\""+"/>");
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: You could start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
<script>
    if (window.screen.width < 481) {
        document.write("<meta name="viewport" content=\"width=480\""+"/>");
    } else {
        document.write("<meta name="viewport" content=\"width=1024\""+"/>");
    }
</script>
```

The code for screen size is simple as it is just `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height`.  I would not recommend targeting a website towards a specific device unless you plan to design the website with the same design patterns as that website.

Comment: Thanks. How do you combine two items like min-width 800 and max-width 1024? < 800 && > 1024?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own Javascript using document.body.offsetWidth.

e.g. if(document.body.offsetWidth < 1024){...}

Or use a library like: http://responsejs.com/